# DRF: how to integrate django-rest-framework-jwt to Djoser

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth

I am planning to build an application with *Django Rest Framework*. I'm more interested in using *Django-Rest-Framework-JWT* authentication mechanism than *Session* or *Token* authentication mechanism.

But all the other packages like *Django-Rest-Auth* and *Djoser* (which helps in registrations process) uses Session and Token Authentication system.

How do I override the Token authentication mechanism in *Djoser* or *Django-Rest-Auth* with *Django-Rest-Framework-JWT*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know this question is almost a year old, but I just figured out how to get **Djoser** and **django-rest-knox** to play along and sure enough the same technique worked with **djangorestframework-jwt** as well. The trick is knowing that **you can use Djoser's account endpoints without using its auth-related endpoints**. You just have to put each library on its own endpoint.

Here's how I set up Django Rest Framework to use JWTs to log in and authenticate against Djoser endpoints (I'm going to take it from start to finish):

First, install **djangorestframework-jwt** and **djoser**:

```
pip install djangorestframework-jwt djoser
```

Specify that you want to use JWTs to authenticate by adding `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` to `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your Django project's `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Next, Add `djoser.urls` and rest_framework_jwt's `obtain_jwt_token` view to your urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework_jwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls')),
    url(r'^auth/login/', jwt_views.obtain_jwt_token, name='auth'),
]
```

That should be everything you need to get started. Just to be safe, run a `migrate` (I spun up a brand-new instance of Django Rest Framework for this post and hadn't yet run the initial commits before this point):

```
python manage.py migrate
```

To test things out, create a new user if you don't already have one:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Once you have a user account, `runserver` and then try logging in to get your JWT:

> http POST http://localhost:800/auth/login/ username=admin password=password

You should get back a token:

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTg2ODI3MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjJ9.JDoVCpfiE0uGhsv9OQfPgPc-wxjjQtcEjwAI6bTLWRM"
}
```

You can then use this token to authenticate against Djoser's **/me/** endpoint to get your profile information. Just include your token within your request's header as **Authorization: JWT**:

> http http://localhost:8000/account/me/ "Authorization: JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTg2ODI3MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjJ9.JDoVCpfiE0uGhsv9OQfPgPc-wxjjQtcEjwAI6bTLWRM"

Here's what I got back:

```
{
    "email": "",
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin"
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty easy to start using JWTs for authentication. My guess is that libraries like **djoser** and **django-rest-auth** focus on Basic, Session, or Token authentication because they're included out of the DRF box and thus are probably the most common method by which people authenticate calls against their server.

The beauty of all this is that it's easy to implement a more secure authentication scheme because Djoser isn't tightly coupled to its own authentication classes - it'll happily respect whatever you set for `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.

Comment: Djoser has recently gained support for JWT based on djangorestframework-jwt - http://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation and http://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication_backends.html#json-web-token-authentication

Comment: @IAmKale I am trying to implement Djoser with Knox token authentication but struggling with URLs and views to make them work together. Is there any tutorial or guide which can help me.

Comment: @gagan I don’t have good leads unfortunately, I haven’t touched these libraries since I originally posted this answer. Was this other answer you commented on not useful after all? It’s the only thing I’d think to link you to after a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961526/2133271

Comment: @IAmKale The post I commented on gave me an idea, how I can merge 2 packages. I started with Djoser, created a user successfully, got installed Knox->did some knox configurations and Djoser stopped working. Now I am nowhere. I am trying to figure out how these 2 packages impact each other and what are the mandatory dependencies/implementations/configurations to make them work together (which I am missing probably).