# How to make centralized Login server with Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, server

Where I work currently there are many Django projects, each running on their own VPS, and each is running under their own subdomain (foo.example.com, bar.example.com, ...) as shown in the following diagram:
[image]

What I want to do is to have a central Django Server that manages all the login process (authorization and authentication) for each application, and when a user logins in `foo.example.com` and then goes to `bar.example.com`, his session keeps active and doesn't need to enter credentials again (user/password), the same if the user logs out, he couldn't see anything on the other projects until he logins in again.

Similar as what Google does when you login on `gmail.com` and go to `youtube.com` or `blogger.com` (**or more similar to what I want to do: you login in `google.com` and go to  `drive.google.com`, `photos.google.com`, `calendar.google.com`**) or any other Google's site, your session keeps active.

Is there any django-package or any other way that would help me accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the django rest framework and login with that.  This will install a session cookie, which you can check every time the user opens a page that they need to be logged in for.  Once the cookie expires, or django expires the cookie, the user is logged out, and pages should not be served to them if your authentication checks are good.  This means that if they log in to the django server anywhere, they remain logged in, even on your page, just like with facebook or google.  When they log out of the django server, anywhere, they will be logged out of your remote pages as well.

You can read more about the django rest framework authentication [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I used [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) package and [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) and it worked so fine!

Comment: Could u tell me how it works?

E.G. user comes to bar.example.com with a token. How your application checks it? Does it make a http request to your auth server to check this token?

Do u have a copy of users table in each bar.example.com or only at auth server? Or do they use the same DB?

Comment: Just using django rest framework, if you have a person sign in at the original server, like in a popup window, then check the authentication with javascript on every page, it will work, but djoser is a more complete solution.

Here's an example of how to juse Json Web Tokens(JWT) through djoser:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939042/drf-how-to-integrate-django-rest-framework-jwt-to-djoser

Answer (score -1):

I could not comment on @shaihulud comment because I don't have up to 50 reputations. To answer the question, I wrote an article that addresses that, for anyone that might run into this problem in the future, you can find the article [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/authenticating-django-applications-with-another-django-app-hosted-separately-905949549fa2)