# How can I use `django-rest-knox` with `django-rest-auth`?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'd like to use [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) to easily make use of the registration and social auth features of [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) in my API.

I'd also like to use [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox), as it provides a token per device, rather than per user.

When creating a user via `django-rest-auth`, it tries to create and return a token. This fails, as it needs to use `django-rest-knox` to generate the token, but I'm unclear on how to do this. Is it possible to get these two packages working together?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done this myself yet but maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939042/drf-how-to-integrate-django-rest-framework-jwt-to-djoser can be a starting point. I'm looking to do the same thing as you too

Comment: I've seen that, wasn't helpful, made a PR on django-rest-auth for this but it's been sitting for a while without review. If you comment on that it might get some notice!

Comment: @StringsOnFire The original django-rest-auth is no longer supported. Please consider using the fork: https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth

Comment: It would be better to understand if you share a traceback and code examples of what / how you are trying to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that instead of using these two packages together, use `dj-rest-auth` (`django-rest-auth` is deprecated). Then, try to implement the logic you need for generating tokens for each device. As you said in your comments, try to make a PR and only work with one of these packages. I know I did not kinda answered your question, but I felt that this should be the correct answer.