# Djoser for DRF with Knox tokens

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, djoser

I'm trying to use djoser with token authentication, but using django-rest-knox tokens.

I have set the `TOKEN_MODEL` to `knox.models.AuthToken`, and the rest framework's `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to `knox.auth.TokenAuthentication`.

I naïvely thought that this would be enough, but it seems that Djoser's inbuilt serializers (create token, and token), don't work properly with the knox tokens. I tried overriding them with custom serializers, but I didn't get anywhere (which is not to say it's not possible, just that I'm bad at this).

It occurred to me that perhaps I should try using Knox's own login views... Is that possible, or can they not be mixed like that? (I'm mainly asking because I don't want to get it to 'work', but find that I've actually introduced a security hole in doing so).

Settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    "TOKEN_MODEL": "knox.models.AuthToken",
    "SERIALIZERS": {"token": "users.serializers.TokenSerializer"},
}
```

Where users.serializers.TokenSerializer is:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auth_token = serializers.CharField(source="token_key")

    class Meta:
        model = settings.TOKEN_MODEL
        fields = ("auth_token",)
```

This is only slightly modified from the original Djoser TokenSerializer. It was throwing an error that AuthToken objects did not have a `key` attribute. Knox tokens seem to call it `token_key`, so I replaced the line:
`auth_token = serializers.CharField(source="key")` with `auth_token = serializers.CharField(source="token_key")`

Now, it doesn't throw an error, but it returns an empty token. Inspecting the actual db shows that it has saved a token with the correct user and creation time, but with 'null' for  digest, salt, and token_key

Comment: Do you overwrite in `Djoser`'s namespace from your project settings. Serializer should overwrite under Serializer namespace in Djsoer settings.

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: can you please add your `settings.py`, i believe you did that appropriately but just want to check.

Comment: @Shakil I've added some more details

Comment: what is `settings.TOKEN_MODEL` stands for, i mean is it knox.models.AuthToken or rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token.

Comment: what is the status of your problem now ? I am really wondering how you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to mixin's `Djoser`'s and `knox`'s additional view point. For that we are going to create an app name `auth` from where we are going to serve all authenticational related end-points. Now our project structure is like

```
MainProject
   -auth
      --__init__.py
      --urls.py
    -mainapp
    ....
```

Now in our `auth` app's urls we are going to serve our necessary end-points for authentication. For that we are going to take help from `Djoser`'s urls [link](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/urls/base.py) and `Knox`'s urls [link](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox/blob/master/knox/urls.py)
And our auth's urls.py will be like following

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from djoser import views as djsoer_views
from knox import views as knox_views

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', djsoer_views.UserViewSet)

User = get_user_model()

djoser_urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^users/create/?$',
        djsoer_views.UserCreateView.as_view(),
        name='user-create'
    ),
    url(
        r'^users/delete/?$',
        djsoer_views.UserDeleteView.as_view(),
        name='user-delete'
    ),
    url(
        r'^users/activate/?$',
        djsoer_views.ActivationView.as_view(),
        name='user-activate'
    ),
    url(
        r'^{0}/?$'.format(User.USERNAME_FIELD),
        djsoer_views.SetUsernameView.as_view(),
        name='set_username'
    ),
    url(r'^password/?$', djsoer_views.SetPasswordView.as_view(), name='set_password'),
    url(
        r'^password/reset/?$',
        djsoer_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
    url(
        r'^password/reset/confirm/?$',
        djsoer_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    url(r'^$', djsoer_views.RootView.as_view(), name='root'),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),   ### If you want to add user view set
]

knox_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'login/', knox_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='knox_login'),
    url(r'logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),
    url(r'logoutall/', knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view(), name='knox_logoutall'),
]

urlpatterns = knox_urlpatterns + djoser_urlpatterns
```

Now we are going to add this urls under our main_app's urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
auth_urls = include('auth.urls')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth/', auth_urls),
    ......

]
```

Now we are going to able to access every end-point like login as `api/auth/login/` or user-create as `api/auth/user/create/` etc.

What i can see that djoser add some additional UserViewset end-point by default mostly you may not like this , you should include what is really needed for you.

Comment: Awesome explanation @Shakil.

Comment: But it's really difficult to make Djoser work with Knox, at least for me :) I've tried a couple of times but as soon as I install Knox, Djoser endpoint which was working earlier for me (register user) stops working. I start getting page not found for every Djoser endpoint immediately after installing Knox.  Can someone suggest anything on this?